# Prove that any finite simple Abelian $X$-group is a $p$-group.

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory, sylow-theory

$\textbf{ Problem No. 11.7 of Isaacs "Algebra: A Graduate Course":}$

> > Let $S$ be a finite simple Abelian $X$-group. Show that there is some prime $p$ such that all nonzero elements of $S$ have order $p$.

$\textbf{Definition and some attempt:}$

An $X$-group is a set of homomorphisms from $S$ to $S$ that takes $s \in S$ to $s^x\in S$, for each $s \in S$ and $x \in X$.

A simple $X$-group has no non-identity, proper, normal subgroups $H$ such that $x(H) ≤ H$ for every homomorphism $x : S \to S$.

Basically we can say that they are modules.

The Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ of $S$ have the property that $x(P) \le P$ for all $x \in  Hom(S,S)$ and of course they are normal subgroups of $S$, so if $S$ is simple as an $X$-group, then either $P=1$ or $P=S$. In other words, for some prime $p$, $S=P$ is a $p$-group.

Now the subgroup $A = \{ s^p : s \in S \}$ also has the property that $x(A) = \{ x(s^p) : s \in S \} = \{ x(s)^p : s \in S \} \le A$. $A$ is normal, and $A \neq S$. Hence $A=1$, and all elements of $S$ have order 1 or $p$.

The same is true if $S$ is torsion rather than finite, but there are infinite
torsion-free simple $X$-groups, like the additive group of the rationals, with
$X=Hom(S,S)$.

But I am not sure if my proof is correct?!

Can someone please complete and correct my proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: @Levent Many thanks!

Comment: @Levent Many thanks! But can you please complete this proof and add some more details? I mean can you also please add your own proof? Thanks!

Comment: Probably I would do the exact same proof. Usually the general method is to construct some characteristic subgroups (or in this case, subgroups that are mapped into themselves under all homomorphisms) to show that the group has to be equal to this characteristic subgroup (like when you show G=P first and G=A in the next step). But I don't understand what you mean by complete the proof. Your proof works and it is complete. Your proof does not work for infinite groups since Sylow theory usually do not behave as it behaves in the finite case but the question is already asked for finite groups.